# How to consume Restful in .net (JSON format)

Tags: c#, .net

I have to connect to a server passing a Json and receiving a Json. What is a simple way to do it using .NET 4.5?

**Getting the Token: (GET)**

Request:

```
https://website.com/rest/v1/OAuth/AccessToken?client=ABCD=&password=ABC&returnFormat=json
```

Result:

```
JSON { "accessTokenResponse": { "token": "12345",  "responseStatus": { "code": "100000", "message": "Service operation completed successfully", "messageDetails": "Access token assigned." } } }
```

**Calling a method: (GET)**

```
https://website.com/rest/v1/OAuth/getEmployees?token=12345=&returnFormat=json
```

How to:

**Send a request and receive it using .net?**

**I tried to use this way, but what is the most recommended?**

```
public string GetRequest(string url) 
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            try 
            {
                var response = request.GetResponse();
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()) 
                {
                    var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex) 
            {
                var errorResponse = ex.Response;
                using (var responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                    var errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: There are many ways to do it in .NET and lots of libraries that make it super easy too. Stack Overflow is not a place to ask for code without trying something first though; try to get it working on your own and ask a question when you have a specific problem. I am voting to close this.

Comment: @JesseWebb I added the code I tried to use, but I would like to know some reference from internet or some good practise, I have ServiceStack here, but I also couldn't use it yet, I am studying how it works still. Any help?

Comment: Thanks for adding the code you have tried so far! For Stack Overflow questions, it is best to include code and the specific problem/error you are encountering because you will be more likely to get an answer. Questions asking "How do I do this?" without enough detail will likely get closed.

Comment: It is also not acceptable to ask for online references/tutorials here. Try Google instead: "C# JSON REST API client" The top search result is the MSDN docs explaining how to do this. The second result is a link to RestSharp, the same library recommended in an answer below.

Comment: For more information on what kind of questions are acceptable on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Great, I could use Servicestack to make it. recommended!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). You can add it through NuGet package manager.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://website.com");
var request = new RestRequest("/rest/v1/OAuth/AccessToken?client=ABCD=&password=ABC&returnFormat=json", Method.GET);
var response = client.Execute<Response>(request).Data;
```

The `Response` class is created from your JSON using [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/). It's an online tool. You paste in your JSON and it generates C# classes.

```
public class ResponseStatus
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string messageDetails { get; set; }
}

public class AccessTokenResponse
{
    public string token { get; set; }
    public ResponseStatus responseStatus { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public AccessTokenResponse accessTokenResponse { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Great, I ended using ServiceStack. Worked!